# Calendly/SFDC flow mofidication

Tags: integration, visual-workflow

Looking to modify this flow so that leads are assigned to a specific owner, not the owner of the integration.

Calendly's article says that's possible (https://blog.calendly.com/salesforce-integration/), but only mentions that you have to modify the flow.

Here is a screenshot of the ending part of the flow[image]

Calendly will either create an event (if lead exists) or create a new lead. So I need to change both 'Record Create' options.

1. Create Event - I tried changing the OwnerID to the ID of the owner who I want to change the event/lead to, but it failed.

   [image]
2. Create Lead

   [image]

Thanks!

Comment: "But it failed" doesn't help. How did it fail? What is the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you'll have to create a record look-up node and insert it before the record create nodes.

In your record look-up node you would run a search to find the owner you want and assign that owner ID to a variable and then assign that variable as the owner of the records:

1. Create a Variable to store the owner ID

[image: Variable]

2. Look up the owner and assign the ID to the variable. Use what ever
   criteria you want to identify the owner. Here I use a bogus Id but
   you can do a much more advanced search if you need.

[image: Lookup]

3. Lastly, use the variable that is storing your ID to set your record
   owner

[image: Create]

4. Position:(excuse the ms paint chop shop)

[image: Position]

Alternatively, if you don't need that much information to find the right owner (if you want to set it to a specific user every time) you can move the lookup to the very beginning of the flow and you wont have to create 3 nodes to perform the same lookup